# playing WAV files in python using Snack

Tags: python, tkinter, wav

So I downloaded Snack and put the Snacklib in python/tcl and put the tkSnack.py into python/Lib but i still dont get any sound.  I'm not getting any errors but im still not getting any sound.Here's my code...

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkSnack import *

root = Tk()

tkSnack.initializeSnack(root)

snd = Sound() 
snd.read('ex1.wav')
snd.play()
```

If anyone has any advice it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be adding the mainloop for tk?

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkSnack import *

root = Tk()

tkSnack.initializeSnack(root)

snd = Sound() 
snd.read('ex1.wav')   <--- Also good to give full path to file
snd.play()
root.mainloop()   <------ main loop
```

See the [manual](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/man/snack2.2/python-man.html), it suggests other ways of loading too.

```
snd = tkSnack.Sound(file='ex1.wav')
```